# kubernetes deploy plugin in Jenkins doesn't update pod

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

I use kubernetes-cd plugin in Jenkins (https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cd/) to deploy my application successfully.

[image]

But, I got a problem, when I re-run the job again, the jenkins doesn't update my pod (doesn't delete and create new pod again), so my changes of code aren't affected. And after I delete the pod manual using kubectl commands in kubernetes cluster and re-run the job, it make changes

Below is my yaml file. Do you know how to fix this ?

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tds-upload
  name: tds-upload
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tds-upload
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tds-upload
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: dev-master:5000/tds-upload:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: tds-upload

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: tds-upload
  name: tds-upload
spec:
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31313
    port: 8889
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8889
  selector:
    app: tds-upload
  type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to make Kubernetes deploy new changes.

1. `kubectl rollout restart deployment myapp`

This is the current way to trigger a rolling update and leave the old replica sets in place for other operations provided by kubectl rollout like rollbacks

2. `kubectl patch deployment my-deployment -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"build\":\"$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA\"}}}}}}"`

Where you can use any name and any value for the label as long as it changes with each build.

You can use the [kubectl cli plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cli-plugin) of Jenkins to execute above commands.

Comment: Thanks @Arghya Sadhu, But I want it auto update when re-run Jenkins job, I think that the reason is the yaml file didn't change so Jenkins doesn't update resources ? Is it right ? In my case, I changed my code, and updated docker images on registry (but keep the same tag and version)

Comment: unless there is some change in yaml it will not update pod..so in the Jenkins job you need add the kubectl patch command or the rollout command

Comment: How can I add it in jenkins ui ?

Comment: Use the kubectl plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cli-plugin

Comment: Thank you, I think that resolve this probem. But I am try another way, I changed my yaml file, rename cotainer to include ${BUILD_NUMBER}, then my yaml file always update after running job and then the pod update again. Mank thanks, your comments very useful for me